# ForeignKey image form field in template

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm trying to access to a ForeignKey classes for images.

```
class Airplane(Aerodyne):
    """ A powered aerodyne with fixed wings. """
    engine = models.CharField('Modèle du moteur', max_length=stgs.MAX_CHAR_SIZE, blank=True, null=True)
    engine_horsepower = models.SmallIntegerField('Puissance du moteur', blank=True, null=True)
    max_range = models.IntegerField("Rayon d'action maximal", blank=True, null=True)
    cruise_speed = models.FloatField('Vitesse de croisière', blank=True, null=True)
    useful_load = models.SmallIntegerField('Charge utile', blank=True, null=True)
    max_passengers = models.SmallIntegerField('Nombre de passagers (pilote[s] compris)', blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "avion"
        verbose_name_plural = "avions"


class AirplaneImage(models.Model):
    """ Images for each airplane """
    model = models.ForeignKey(Airplane, related_name='images')
    image = models.ImageField('Image', upload_to='aircraft/airplane/', null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "image"
        verbose_name_plural = "images"
```

And this is what I tried in my form template :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
         <label {% if form.images.errors %}class="error"{% endif %}>{{ form.images.label_tag }}
            {% render_field form.images %}
        </label>
        {% if form.images.errors %}
            <small class="error">{{ form.images.errors.as_text }}</small>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</div>
```

Normaly, if my ForeignKey has a `related_name`, I should be able to access through it, no ?

EDIT : This is what I'm trying to achieve. I want to add the possibility for my users to upload pictures for their airplanes. I've already the models, an Airplane which inherit from Aircraft and Aerodyne, and the AirplaneImage which'll contain all the images. Now I want to add the field to the form. The user must be able to upload 1 or 2 or 3 or x photos (It'll run in local).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are trying to access form fields like they are model fields. Forms and models are very different, obviously.

Can you tell us what you are actually trying to achieve. What is the context of the snippet?